# How can I force URL parameters to lowercase in Apache2 2.4 on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: url, apache2, lowercase

Apache2 2.4 (Ubuntu) force URL parameters to lowercase not working

Problem:
/apartment/Munich => /apartment/munich (all letters lowercase!!)

I ´ve tried following solutions from multiple websites
and added these lines in
/etc/apache2/**apache2.conf** (httpd.conf not included in Ubuntu 22.04)

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /${lowercase:$1} [R=301,L]

But service apache2 restart fails because of errors without any logfile.

Is there a current solutions that works for Apache 2.4/ubuntu 22.04? Server rules would be preferred, because should be more efficient than .htaccess rules.